# Trying to setup Magento Cron

Tags: php, macos, apache, cron

I am trying to setup magento Cron Jobs. This might be easy fix because I am somewhat a newb to crontabs

`crontab -e`

I added the following. website is the root directory of magento in which I was able to identify both the cron.sh and the cron.php

`1 * * * *  /bin/sh /Library/WebServer/Documents/website/cron.sh`

Then in cron.php i put the following

```
try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
    Mage::log("Cron run"); //Add this line and you will get a log entry
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
```

Small debugging tip I found on the web. But I dont believe I see anything logging

As of right now I am working on Mac OS Maverick.

When I RUN

`php /Library/WebServer/Documents/website/cron.php`

I get the following

```
# location of the php binary
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi

MODE=""
if [ ! "$2" = "" ] ; then
        MODE=" $2"
fi

PHP_BIN=`which php`

# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`

#       prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
else
    if  ! ps auxwww | grep "$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
fi
```

Comment: What is written in cron.sh, have you run the cron.php in cron.sh

Comment: Yea I have, the resposne isnt that great. I added to the post. And I have no clue what that means

Comment: forgot to put the php in front. when i put php in front i get the above result